# How to make CSS2DRenderer labels behaving like SpriteMaterial for scaled objects with parents?

Tags: three.js

I have an existing project, a model of the Solar system, where planets and moons are labeled with text. To create the labels I used sprites (`SpriteMaterial`) and that worked well. (Below there is the result - you can zoom in to have a closer look at labels)

As you can see, labels are rendered nicely next to their parents, and also scaling is relative to the scaling of their parents.

```js
var camera, scene, renderer;

init();
animate();

function init() {

  camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, .1, 2000);
  camera.position.z = 3;

  scene = new THREE.Scene();

  var object;
  var label;

  var ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight(0xcccccc, 0.4);
  scene.add(ambientLight);

  var pointLight = new THREE.PointLight(0xffffff, 0.8);
  camera.add(pointLight);
  scene.add(camera);

  var map = new THREE.TextureLoader().load('https://threejs.org/examples/textures/UV_Grid_Sm.jpg');
  map.wrapS = map.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
  map.anisotropy = 16;

  var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
    map: map,
    side: THREE.DoubleSide
  });

  //

  sun = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.SphereBufferGeometry(1, 20, 10), material);
  sun.position.set(0, 0, 0);
  label = makeTextSprite("Sun");
  sun.add(label)
  scene.add(sun);

  ratioOfJupiterToSun = 0.1
  jupiter = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.SphereBufferGeometry(1, 20, 10), material);
  jupiter.position.set(1.5, 0, 0);
  jupiter.scale.set(ratioOfJupiterToSun, ratioOfJupiterToSun, ratioOfJupiterToSun)
  label = makeTextSprite("Jupiter");
  jupiter.add(label)
  sun.add(jupiter);

  ratioOfGanymedeToJupiter = 0.1
  ganymede = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.SphereBufferGeometry(1, 20, 10), material);
  ganymede.scale.set(ratioOfGanymedeToJupiter, ratioOfGanymedeToJupiter, ratioOfGanymedeToJupiter)
  ganymede.position.set(4, 0, 0);
  label = makeTextSprite("Ganymede");
  ganymede.add(label)
  jupiter.add(ganymede);



  //

  renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
    antialias: true
  });
  renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
  renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);

  const controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
  controls.minDistance = 1.7
  controls.maxDistance = 3

  document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

  window.addEventListener('resize', onWindowResize, false);

}

function onWindowResize() {

  camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
  camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

  renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);

}

//

function animate() {

  requestAnimationFrame(animate);

  render();

}

function render() {

  camera.lookAt(scene.position);

  renderer.render(scene, camera);

}

function makeTextSprite(message, centerX = 1.5, centerY = 1.7) {
  var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
  canvas.width = 256;
  canvas.height = 256;
  var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  ctx.font = "38pt Arial";
  ctx.fillStyle = "white";
  ctx.textAlign = "left";
  ctx.fillText(message, 0, 38);
  var tex = new THREE.Texture(canvas);
  tex.needsUpdate = true;
  var spriteMat = new THREE.SpriteMaterial({
    map: tex
  });
  var sprite = new THREE.Sprite(spriteMat);
  sprite.center.set(centerX, centerY);
  return sprite;
}
```

```css
body {
  color: #eee;
  font-family: Monospace;
  font-size: 13px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #000;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#info {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 5px;
}

a {
  color: #0080ff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/98/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://threejs.org/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>
<script src="https://threejs.org/examples/js/renderers/CSS2DRenderer.js"></script>
```

The problem with sprites is that they use raster graphics for labeling. Sometimes the quality is not sufficient.

That's why I would like to reproduce the same effect with `THREE.CSS2DRenderer`. Unfortunately the best approximation I achieved is this

```js
var camera, scene, renderer, labelRenderer;

init();
animate();

function init() {

  camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, .1, 2000);
  camera.position.z = 3;

  scene = new THREE.Scene();

  var object;
  var label;

  var ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight(0xcccccc, 0.4);
  scene.add(ambientLight);

  var pointLight = new THREE.PointLight(0xffffff, 0.8);
  camera.add(pointLight);
  scene.add(camera);

  var map = new THREE.TextureLoader().load('https://threejs.org/examples/textures/UV_Grid_Sm.jpg');
  map.wrapS = map.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
  map.anisotropy = 16;

  var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
    map: map,
    side: THREE.DoubleSide
  });

  //

  sun = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.SphereBufferGeometry(1, 20, 10), material);
  sun.position.set(0, 0, 0);
  label = makeTextLabel("Sun");
  sun.add(label)
  scene.add(sun);

  ratioOfJupiterToSun = 0.1
  jupiter = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.SphereBufferGeometry(1, 20, 10), material);
  jupiter.position.set(1.5, 0, 0);
  jupiter.scale.set(ratioOfJupiterToSun, ratioOfJupiterToSun, ratioOfJupiterToSun)
  label = makeTextLabel("Jupiter");
  jupiter.add(label)
  sun.add(jupiter);

  ratioOfGanymedeToJupiter = 0.1
  ganymede = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.SphereBufferGeometry(1, 20, 10), material);
  ganymede.scale.set(ratioOfGanymedeToJupiter, ratioOfGanymedeToJupiter, ratioOfGanymedeToJupiter)
  ganymede.position.set(4, 0, 0);
  label = makeTextLabel("Ganymede");
  ganymede.add(label)
  jupiter.add(ganymede);

  renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
    antialias: true
  });
  renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
  renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);

  const controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
  controls.minDistance = 2
  controls.maxDistance = 3

  document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

  labelRenderer = new THREE.CSS2DRenderer();
  labelRenderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
  labelRenderer.domElement.style.position = 'absolute';
  labelRenderer.domElement.style.top = '0';
  labelRenderer.domElement.style.pointerEvents = 'none';
  document.body.appendChild(labelRenderer.domElement);

  window.addEventListener('resize', onWindowResize, false);

}

function onWindowResize() {

  camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
  camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

  renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
  labelRenderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
}

//

function animate() {

  requestAnimationFrame(animate);

  render();

}

function render() {

  var timer = Date.now() * 0.0005;

  // camera.position.x = Math.sin(timer) * 400;
  // camera.position.z = Math.cos(timer) * 400;

  camera.lookAt(scene.position);

  scene.traverse(function(object) {

    if (object.isMesh === true) {

      //object.rotation.x = timer;
      //object.rotation.z = timer;

    }

  });

  renderer.render(scene, camera);
  labelRenderer.render(scene, camera);
}

function makeTextLabel(label) {
  var text = document.createElement('div');
  text.style.color = 'rgb(255, 255, 255)';
  text.style.marginTop = '1.7em';
  text.style.marginLeft = '-4em';
  text.className = 'label';
  text.textContent = label;
  return new THREE.CSS2DObject(text);
}
```

```css
body {
  color: #eee;
  font-family: Monospace;
  font-size: 13px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #000;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

a {
  color: #0080ff;
}

.label {
  color: #FFF;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 44px;
  padding: 2px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/98/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://threejs.org/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>
<script src="https://threejs.org/examples/js/renderers/CSS2DRenderer.js"></script>
```

As you can see it works partially: labels respect their parents' coordinate system (world matrix). That's why their position is relative. But scale isn't. All labels are of the same size.

Also I would like the labels to be slightly shifted to the bottom left, like I had it done with sprites. But the best way I could find to do it is:

```
text.style.marginTop = '3em';
text.style.marginLeft = '-4em';
```

and this obviously also doesn't take parents' scale into account.

Do you have any idea on how to make it resembling the original?

Code for the two examples at jsfiddle:

- sprites ([jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/lguminski/1L7t0h4r/))
- CSS2DRenderer ([jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/lguminski/ctaofqr8/))

r. 98

Edit: hiding snippets to make the post more readable

Comment: or maybe the scaling should be already working, and it is a bug to report?

Answer (score 2):

It's not a bug to report. The problem is that you're using `CSS2DRenderer`, but it sounds that you're looking for behavior that's provided by `CSS3DRenderer`. You can see it in action [in the examples section](https://threejs.org/examples/?q=css#css3d_periodictable) and how it behaves when you zoom in/out.

You can read more about it [in the docs](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#examples/renderers/CSS3DRenderer). Keep in mind that you'll also have to create `CSS3DObject`s instead of 2D. Then you can position them wherever you want just like any other 3dObject: `.position.set(x, y, z);`, and `scale.set(x, y, z);`

#### Update:

If you *must* use CSS2D, you could perform your own scaling by calculating the distance from each label to the camera.

```
// Create a Vec3 that holds the label's position
var start = new Vector3();
start.copy(label.position);

// Create a var that holds the distance to the camera
var dist = start.distanceTo(camera.position);

// Apply falloff, then turn that into the label's scale
var size = 1 / dist;
```

Now you can use `size` to scale the label, either via CSS `transform: scale(x);` or otherwise.

Comment: I would like to achieve the effect that no matter how I rotate planets, the labels are always flat and facing user. So basically 2D.

CSS3DObjects do not behave this way. Camera rotates around them. To make them looking flat, on every move I would need to recalculate their orientation to keep them orthogonal to camera. It is an interesting idea, but I am worried that it would be quite costly given that I have many labels in the scene.

Comment: Just added an update where you can calculate scale by distance to the camera, if you must use CSS2DRenderer.

Comment: Thank you. This however doesn't solve scaling that should be relative to label's parent (which is a star, planer or moon). I can extract the scale with `label.parent.matrixWorld.decompose(p,q,s)`. But there are still 2 problems left: 1. I would need to recalculate margins (`style.marginLeft`, `style.marginTop`) in a similar way. 2. I would need to calculate all this on every move. So performance-wise it doesn't seem to be better than keeping 3D labels (`CSS3DObjects`) orthogonal. In that case at least I wouldn't need to recalculate the scale. Nothing seems to be as good as sprites..

Comment: CSS3D performs a lot of calculations to get the transformation matrices. Rotations, for instance, require several trig functions. Just because you don't see them, it doesn't mean they're not happening under the hood. Yes, you'd need to do work to achieve the desired result, but it doesn't mean it won't work.

Comment: You are probably right. Let me explore the idea of keeping 3D labels orthogonal, to mimic 2D behaviour. If this proves doable, I will approve your answer, because you pushed me this direction.

Comment: Ok. Also, a tip: Using CSS `transform: translate(-50%, -50%);` is much easier than manually calculating `style.marginLeft` & `style.marginTop` in pixel values. Might save you a lot of tinkering.

Comment: I have a partial success -> [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/lguminski/3s6a7h8n/). Now 3D labels are always facing camera and they don't rotate. But there are 2 problems: moving the label to the bottom left of its parent planet is beyond my quaternion math skills. 2. `onBeforeRender` is not called on `CSS3DObject`, so I had to attach the handler to parent. This means that in cases when label is still visible in the scene, but parent not, it won't work. So it looks like a dead end.